# flutter: Convert Text and other widgets to JSON (or another solution to add parameters to routes when generating programmatically)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bunch of `Activity`s that keep track of the state of user activities in the app. Ideally, I'd also like to add information about how the Activity should appear as a MenuButton. I tried adding the first aspect, a simple Text Widget, but it immediately failed since the Text widget cannot be converted to JSON.

```
class Activity {
  String state;
  bool visible;
  DateTime visibleAfter;
  bool firstView;
  Widget text;   // <----- this doesn't work

  Activity(this.state, this.visible, this.visibleAfter, this.firstView, this.text);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'state': state,
        'visible': visible,
        'visibleAfter': visibleAfter.toIso8601String(),
        'firstView': firstView,
        'text': text,   // <----- this doesn't work
      };

  factory Activity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Activity(
        json['state'], json['visible'], DateTime.parse(json['visibleAfter']), json['firstView'], json['text']);
  }
}
```

My fallback has been to have a Map in the main page that I could use to build the MenuMain buttons. However, it now appears to be insufficient now that I wish to pass a callback function to certain routes. When I try and add a callback function in the Map, I get an error "Only static members can access initializers".

TLDR: Not sure how I can add parameters to call routes programatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dart converter library to parse your Json, you don't need to create your own implementation. According to the docs [Dart Convert library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) you can use Json Decoder and Encoder to do that.

Also for passing callback as parameters, you should try to create a Function attribute in your Activity class, if it makes sense to you.
eg.

```
final Function callback;
```

Then you can pass this Function attribute to another route using Navigator:

```
  Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed('/yourroute', arguments: {
  'callback': activity.callback
});
```

And then in your other route you can get the callback/function attribute like this:

```
    final routeArgs =
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
final activityCallback = routeArgs['callback'];
```